# Trying to tick only checkboxes that contain certain selector in Javascript/jQuery on third-party website

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, attributes

I am on a website and I am trying to find attributes I can use to select or deselect the checkboxes (by certain criteria)

For example

Mike [x]
John [ ]

I want to select the Mike box only using the console on Chrome.

My code is

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input:checkbox[name=Mike]").prop("checked",true)'))
  .filter(input => input.value === 'on')
  .forEach(input => input.click())
```

Would anybody be able to help?

Comment: There is no native prop method for HTML Element Collections

Comment: That's not even a method.  It's included in the selector.  Which looks like a typo, before @LucaKiebel 's point is still valid

Comment: I mean if you wanted to just put as much stuff into the selector as possible you could do something like `document.querySelectorAll('input:checkbox:checked[name="Mike"][value="on"]')` and then forEach off that

Comment: I'm struggling to find the "Valid Selector"

Answer (score 0):

Using vanilla JavaScript :

```js
function mikeCheckBox ()
{
  document.querySelectorAll( 
    'input[ type = checkbox ][ name = Mike ][ value = on ]:checked' 
  ).forEach( checkbox => checkbox.click() );
}

mikeCheckBox();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="on" name="Mike" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" value="on" name="Mike"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="on" name="Sam"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="Mike" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" value="on" name="Sam"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="on" name="Mike"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="on" name="Mike" checked/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[name=Mike]").forEach(node => { node.checked = true })
```

you can edit the selector to select other checkboxes